# How can i reach data Firebase with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fill my CurrentUser object with the same information as the uid of the logged in user when my users login to the application

My databaseService :

```
final CollectionReference userCollection =
  Firestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<User> getCurrentUserData(String uid) async{
var doc = userCollection.document(uid);
```

And My Home Page :

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
final FirebaseUser currentUser;
HomeScreen({@required this.currentUser});

@override
_HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
```

And My CurrentUser Model :

```
class CurrentUser {
static String name;
static String lastName;
static String uid;
static String phone;
static String addresses;
static String photoString;
static int cityId;
static int districtId;
static List<Loss> userLosses;
}
```

But i cant figure out connect them
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it like this:

```
Future<User> getCurrentUserData(String uid)async {
var docRef = await userCollection.document(uid).get();
User currentUser = User.fromJson(docRef.data);
currentUser.uid=docRef.documentID;
return currentUser;
}
```

docRef.data is <String,dynamic> map and just i change my user class like this:

```
factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return User(
    name: json['Name'].toString(),
    lastName: json['LastName'].toString(),
    phone: json['Phone'].toString(),
    photoString: json['PhotoString'].toString(),
    districtId: int.parse(json['DistrictId'].toString()),
    cityId: int.parse(json['CityId'].toString()),
    addresses: json['Addresess'].toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the firebase authentication then you can use `FiresbaseAuth.instance.currentUser`, it will return a FirebaseUser object that will contain the info of the current user.

Comment: i cant reach my 'users' document like this